# Image will look broken when using image texture

Tags: texturing

If you use the <kbd>E</kbd> key to apply the image texture to the increased mesh, the image becomes forced to increase width or height.

Resizing the image or mesh deployment in the UV editor will not change anything.

[image]

As shown in the attached image, it doesn't matter to change the size of the mesh, but only if you expand it through <kbd>E</kbd> key, the texture is broken like that.

Comment: You need to manually fix the UV map. Extrude does not modify the UV map...

Comment: This is one of the features that has been addressed in 2.9

Comment: yea, if you use blender 2.9, the UV should adapt to your extrusions.